# Is it possible to use ALL, ANY, or CMP functions of python to know if all items in list X are smaller than corresponding items in list Y?

Tags: list, compare

Say:

```
X=[1,2,3,4]
Y=[10,20,30,40]
Z=[10,0,0,0]
```

Using built-in functions, is there an easy way to determine if:

```
For each i:

Xi =< Yi  -->True

Zi =< Xi  -->False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#all) and [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip):

> Xi =< Yi  -->True

```
all(x <= y for x, y in zip(X, Y))
```

> Zi =< Xi  -->False

```
all(z <= x for x, z in zip(X, Z))
```